# Nodejs express get the real origin hostname to prevent spoof

Tags: node.js, express

Currently i'm using NodeJS & Express and obtaining the hostname from `req.hostname`, e.g. `example.com`

However, when the client call the API (e.g. `http://example.com/hello`), if the client change the `host` value from the http header (e.g. change to `bar.com`), the result obtain from `req.hostname` (where the `example.com` hosted) will return `bar.com` instead of `example.com`.

Anyone know how to get the real origin hostname from nodejs?

**Edit: @Marc suggest to check against local env variable**

However, the application is shared among multiple domains, it only helps when the application is using by 1 domain.

Comment: Using req.headers.origin doesn't show up on localhost but it does show up on the real server with the domain name

Comment: @AliAzmoodeh Thats bad, because headers can be faked. Dont trust the client. In my opinion if thats a problem, set a env variable and check the host header against the setted env.

Comment: @Marc thanks for the suggestion but my application shared among multiple domains, i still can't differentiate the real hostname accurately.

Comment: @Jerry Specify multiple domains in the env var, and split them via `,` or what ever, with [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?retiredLocale=de).

Comment: @Marc I still can't check whether domain A spoofing domain B although both domain are whitelisted. E.g.  `foo.com` & `bar.com` both is in the env variable, we can tell when the client is spoofing `foo.com` as `baz.com`, but we can't tell when `foo.com` spoof as `bar.com`

Comment: Another option could be a nginx in front of your node app. Then a spoofed request wouldnt be handeld by nginx. But why cant you detect when "when `foo.com` spoof as `bar.com`, just do a `process.env.DOMAINS.split(",").include(req.hostname)`. I dont get it tbh. Lets discuss here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252845/75811245

Comment: `if the client change the host value` - is the client an app? If so it doesn't have a host value thus spoofing is a valid use to convince your server to return some data for an app.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by M Surya, you should be getting a header added by your reverse proxy noting the original host. The reverse proxy should also be stripping out any "X-Real-IP" and "X-Forwarded-For" headers that come externally.

You should know and inherently trust your Reverse Proxy, presumably it's also doing your SSL offloading for you. You can designate it's IP address to be trusted by your express app and allow express to do the heavy lifting with the `trust proxy` functionality.

Documentation here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer finds you well. M Surya answer is correct and pretty much what most of the user's would want. However Yes, as mentioned "headers can be faked".

One way you can follow is, use a reverse proxy like Nginx to set a custom header with the real origin hostname and then read that header in your Node.js application. More About it [Here](https://philio.me/backend-server-host-name-as-a-custom-header-with-nginx/).

```
http {
    ...
    # Show server host name as header
    add_header X-Backend-Server $hostname;
}
```

This will add a custom header named `X-Backend-Server` to all responses sent by Nginx, containing the real origin hostname as its value.